# How to create multiple Folders/subfolders with user input using batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

I want to create folders/subfolders with user inputs using batch file automatically, like this:

```
 C:\123_XXX-Mainfolder1
           ¥ 123_XXX-Subfolder1
           ¥ 123_XXX-Subfolder2

XXX=User Input
```

Anyone please help me for coding.

Comment: whats your trying code?

Comment: i don't know how create a batch file for this.

Comment: Please make an effort and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44225853/edit) and try to add some code that you have tried until now !

Comment: Helping implies that you did some work on your own, not just requesting code for free! StackOverflow is also not a tutorial site, so if you don't know anything about batch files at all, you are simply wrong here! Please re-read the [tour] and learn [ask]!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess…

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "src=C:\"
Set "pre=123"
Set "dir=MainFolder1"
Set "sub=SubFolder"

Set/P "xxx=Please enter your input here: "

For %%I In (1 2
) Do If Not Exist "%src%%pre%_%xxx%-%dir%\%pre%_%xxx%-%sub%%%I\" (
    Echo=MD "%src%%pre%_%xxx%-%dir%\%pre%_%xxx%-%sub%%%I")

Timeout -1
```

If the output in the prompt window looks okay then remove `Echo=` from line 11 and the entire last line. You can obviously change the text string, `Please enter your input here` on line 7 accordingly.

Please note that there is no kind of input validation provided here so entering nothing at all or entering certain things could cause you issues. *Input validation can become extremely involved and therefore outside of the scope of your question*

Comment: With extensions enabled (usually standard setting) there is no need to create an intermediate folder manually (see `help md`).

Comment: @LotPings, to whom is your comment intended?

Comment: Since you inserted the (here) unnecessary `if not exist ..` i meant both of you ;-)

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me; the OP, in the little they offered, did mention the creation of folders and subfolders. The code doesn't create any intermediate folder structure, it creates a main directory and sub directory in one pass, and an additional subdirectory along side it. The `If Not Exist` whilst unnecessary is good practice, I don't want to make a directory which may already exist, some people are happy to do so and redirect the error message, I'm not.